# how to output xsl:message in powershell

Tags: powershell, xslt

I've created a script (based on other peoples code) to run XSLT transformation via powershell

```
function TransformXML{
param ($xml, $xsl, $argsList, $output)
    $xslt_settings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings;
    $XmlUrlResolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver;
    $xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;
    $xslt.Load($xsl,$xslt_settings,$XmlUrlResolver);        
    $XmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($output)        
    $xslt.Transform($xml,$argsList, $XmlWriter)
}
```

The Transformation works but what I cannot work out is how to get it to output xsl:message

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> <xsl:message>hello</xsl:message></xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have found "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xsltmessageencounteredeventargs?view=netframework-4.8" but have no idea how to implement this in powershell.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Register-ObjectEvent is suggested in https://wensveen.wordpress.com/2012/11/12/synchronous-net-event-handling-with-powershell/. `Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $argsList -EventName "XsltMessageEncountered" -Action { Write-Host ("Message: " + $EventArgs.Message) }`. Note that XslCompiledTransform is an XSLT 1.0 processor so having `version="2.0"` in your XSLT code might make it ignore constructs not supported/usable in XSLT 1, unless you have a very good reason to use `version="2.0"` with an XSLT 1 processor I would suggest to use `version="1.0"` to get clear and complete error messages.

Comment: Do note that `xsl:message` it's not a top level element... That stylesheet should report an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `Register-ObjectEvent` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7):

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $argsList -EventName "XsltMessageEncountered" -Action { Write-Host ("Message: " + $EventArgs.Message) };
```